# How to proper write an upstart script?

Tags: neo4j, upstart

I am trying to write an upstart script to be put in `/etc/init` to start neo4j on start-up. I am on a VM with Ubuntu 16.04. My file, taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759706/how-to-write-an-upstart-script-for-a-background-service-db) is named `neo4j1.conf` and looks like:

description "neo4j1 upstart"

```
start on local-filesystems
stop on shutdown

script
  echo $$ > /var/run/neo4j1_start.pid
  exec /home/myusr/neo4j/bin/neo4j console
end script

pre-start script
  echo "[`date`] Neo4j  Starting" >> /var/log/neo4j1.log
end script

pre-stop script
  rm /var/run/neo4j1_start.pid
  echo "[`date`] Neo4j Stopping" >> /var/log/neo4j1.log
end script
```

However it is not working, i.e., when rebooting the service is not active and there is no process.

I tried to remove `>> /var/log/neo4j2.log` as suggested in other link, I tried to comment the creation and deletion of `neo4j1_start.pid` because of permissions but it did not work.

How can I create a proper script?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu16.04 i Will modify the question too

Comment: Xenial uses `systemd` by default. Unless you have purposefully and manually switched to Upstart, you are likely doing the wrong thing here.

Comment: I partially managed with `/etc/init.d` but I am still having some problems described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56888329/1714692